# How to make JSON in Slim php

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, slim

my code is:-

```
<?php
include 'dbConfig.php';
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$slim_app = new \Slim\Slim();
$slim_app->get('/getStore','getStore');
$slim_app->run();

function getStore(){
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    try{
        $data = array();
        $pdo = getDB();
        $sql = "SELECT cat_title,cat_id FROM category";
        $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($result as $value) {
        //var_dump($value);
            $data[] = $value;
        }
        $menu = array('menus'=>$data);
        echo json_encode($menu);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $app->response()->setStatus(404);
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
?>
```

And Here is my output:

```
{
    "menus": [
        {
            "cat_title": "Travel",
            "cat_id": "8"
        },
        {
            "cat_title": "Just Kidding",
            "cat_id": "9"
        },
        {
            "cat_title": "Lifestyle",
            "cat_id": "12"
        },
        {
            "cat_title": "Love & Gifts",
            "cat_id": "14"
        },
        {
            "cat_title": "Foodies Bay",
            "cat_id": "15"
        },
        {
            "cat_title": "Ladies Only",
            "cat_id": "16"
        },
        {
            "cat_title": "Megastores",
            "cat_id": "26"
        },
        {
            "cat_title": "Sweet Home",
            "cat_id": "27"
        },
        {
            "cat_title": "Miscellaneous",
            "cat_id": "28"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have another table called store where above cat_id and store cat_id have relationship
store table:

```
id cat_id name image value
```

I want to select name, image, value from store table and make json for each category means i want like this:

```
{
    "menus": [
        {
            "cat_title": "Travel",
            "cat_id": "8",
            "store": [
                {
                    "store_id": 1,
                    "store_name": "abc",
                    "image": "xyz.jpg",
                    "value": "abc"
                },
                {
                    "store_id": 2,
                    "store_name": "abc",
                    "image": "xyz.jpg",
                    "value": "abc"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How i can achieve it?
Please help

Comment: What kind of DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your resultset is already an array, you don't need to create a new one.

For what you need to do, I'd declare a prepared statement and, for each row in the category resultset, I'd execute the prepared statement with the row cat_id. Then I'd say the row 'store' property is my array of stores:

```
$pdo = getDB();
$sql = "SELECT cat_title,cat_id FROM category";
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);

$storeSTMT = $pdo->prepare("SELECT store_id, store_name, image, value FROM store WHERE cat_id=:cat_id");

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $storeSTMT->execute([':cat_id'=>$value['cat_id']]);
    $result[$key]['store']=$storeSTMT->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

$menu = array('menus'=>$result);
echo json_encode($menu);
```

This isn't the only way to do this. You could also query for a join between the two tables and parse the result to generate a nested array. Your mileage may vary.

PD: this isn't related with Slim Framework at all.